# AForge WriteVideoFrame High Memory Usage in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, aforge

I have a list of frames for my video. It contains byte arrays. I am using this to prevent high memory usage, and it works just fine. But when i try to save these frames, memory usage is going way to up and in some cases it cause out of memory exception.

```
VideoFileWriter _writer = new VideoFileWriter();
_writer.Open(newRecordedDataFile, videoSource.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Width, videoSource.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Height, 20, VideoCodec.Default);

for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.Count; i++)
{
    var array = bitmaps[i];

    using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        mStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
        mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream))
        {
            _writer.WriteVideoFrame(bm);
        }
    }
}

bitmaps.Clear();
```

How can i prevent this high memory usage?

Comment: How is this related to WPF? The Bitmap class is WinForms. As a note, when `var array`is a byte array, you can simply write `new MemoryStream(array)` and drop Write and Seek.

Comment: @Clemens, This is a WPF project. new MemoryStream(array) does the same thing, but simpler. Changed that, thanks. And I need to use System.Drawing.Bitmap class for WriteVideoFrame.